# Blog posts from category isn't displayed

Tags: php, pyrocms, pyrocms-lex

I've created a page and then put this code

```
<section class="cont_pad">
    <div class="container_12">
        <article class="grid_8">
            {{ blog:posts limit="5" offset="5" category="adultos" }}
            <section class="post">
                {{ if imagen_portada }}
                <div class="postimg"><img src="{{ url:site }}files/thumb/{{ imagen_portada.id }}/610/220" class="pic2" alt="{{title}}" title="{{title}}"/></div>
                {{ endif }}
                <div class="entry-date">
                    <div class="posttime">           
                        <h3>{{ helper:date timestamp=created_on }}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="entry-utility">
                        <a href="/users/view/{{ author_id }}"> {{ asset:image file="blog/icon1.png" }} {{ user:display_name user_id=author_id }}</a> 
                        <br/>
                        {{ if category }}
                        <span><a href="{{ url:site }}blog/category/{{ category:slug }}">{{ asset:image file="blog/icon2.png" }} {{ category:title }}</a></span>
                        {{ endif }}
                        {{ if keywords }}
                        <span><a href="{{ url:site }}blog/tagged/{{ keyword }}">{{ asset:image file="blog/icon2.png" }} {{ keyword }}</a></span>
                        {{ endif }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="entry-text">
                    <h3 class="posttitle"><a href="{{ url }}">{{ title }}</a></h3>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                        {{ intro }}
                        <p><a href="{{ url }}">{{ helper:lang line="blog:read_more_label" }}</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            {{ /blog:posts }}
            {{ pagination }}
        </article>
        <article class="grid_4 last-col">
            <aside id="sidebar">
                {{ widgets:area slug="widgets_blog_adultos" }}
            </aside>
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
```

inside to show posts from category "adultos" but I'm not getting nothing. I have one post and it's LIVE in this category. What is wrong? I read [Blog Plugin Docs](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/plugins/blog) also check the Blog Plugin Code at package "PyroCMS\Core\Modules\Blog\Plugins" and can't find where it fails. Also and related to this same question, can I paginate trough all the posts? I need some help here because I can't find what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the timezone on the computer set up wrong? If PyroCMS thinks the "Publish Date" is in the future it wont show it on the frontend.

Comment: really? Don't know the cause but things start working from one moment to another and alone I didn't touch nothing, maybe cache is the problem

Comment: I imagine your timezone was wrong the entire time and waiting a few hours made the article no longer be in the future.